# What to do with a terminal launch script

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I need a terminal to launch with two tabs and I figured what a script should look like, but what do I need to do with it? Putting path to .sh file into custom command option results in infinite terminal windows spawning.

Comment: Make the script executable and then run it?

Comment: Yeah, already did that. I mean, isn't it possible to pass this script as a "parameter" when launching terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tilix, which offers a lot of configuration flexibility. First create a profile with two tabs (or split terminals) then save it as, say,  "myDefault".

Then add an alias to your ~/.bashrc

alias myterm="tilix -p myDefault"

then use myterm to launch it.

Hope this helps!